# woocommerce - change the html of products in category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

product's html looks like this:

```
<li class="post-13 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-printer instock">
    <a href="http://xxx">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://xx" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" />
        <h3>abc</h3>
        <span class="price"><span class="amount">15.86&nbsp;&euro;</span></span>
    </a>
    <div class="gridlist-buttonwrap">
        <a href="xx?add-to-cart=13" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="13" data-product_sku="" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Buy</a>
    </div>
    <hr />          
</li>
```

Is it possible to move the price next to the button?

```
<li class="post-13 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-printer instock">
    <a href="http://xxx">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://xx" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" />
        <h3>abc</h3>
    </a>
    <div class="abc">
        <a href="xx?add-to-cart=13" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="13" data-product_sku="" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Buy</a>
        <span class="price"><span class="amount">15.86&nbsp;&euro;</span></span>
    </div>          
 </li>
```

The only way I have found out it that I should edit core of the plugin, which is useless because I will loose all changes after updates.

Edit: for example [this theme](http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=sliding), they have this structure:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://demo2.woothemes.com/sliding/shop/yellow-necklace/" style="width: 192px; height: 295px;">
        <img width="192" height="295" src="http://demo2.woothemes.com/sliding/files/2011/11/yellow-necklace-192x295.jpg" class="attachment-woo_sliding_slider wp-post-image" alt="yellow-necklace" />
        <div class="meta">
            <h3>Yellow Necklace</h3>
            <span class="slider-price"><span class="amount">&pound;19.00</span></span>
        </div>

    </a>

</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override a template file and that will not be updated when you update woocommerce.

From the WooCommerce [docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

> Alternatively, you can edit these files in an upgrade safe way through
>   overrides. Simply copy it into a directory within your theme named
>   /woocommerce, keeping the same file structure.
>
> Example: To overide the admin order notification, copy:
>   woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to
>   yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php

Comment: yes, I know, but I havent find any template file where I can edit this

Comment: did you find a solution? Same problem here.